# Will rm -rf * remove all files/folders in the current directory?

Tags: shell, globbing

Will `rm -rf *` remove all files/folders in the current directory ? I want to make sure the wildcard `*` won't move up in upper directories and erase all my filesystem. :D

I remember doing `chmod 777 .* -R` to `chmod` hidden files and it `chmod`ed all my filesystem. Obviously, I was on the root account.

Comment: This is why I'd do `rm -rf ./*` and explicitly specify the current directory... but Ankur seems to say it doesn't matter anyway.

Comment: @Mark: what is the difference between .. and ./..? You can try to cd ./.. and see where you end up :)

Comment: @Johan: No difference... I guess it just makes more sense in my crazy head :D

Comment: @Mark: easy mistake to do :)

Comment: mpen, this looks horrible since you could miss that `.`, or accidentally type a space between `.` and `/`, during typing.

Answer (score 16):

No, if you did not tweak your shell a lot this will not remove files or directories starting with a `.`. To remove them, too, you can either list them explicitly

```
rm -rf .file .dir
```

or use the right glob patterns (thanks Chris)

```
rm -rf .[^.]* ..?*
```

**EDIT** The point here is that you cannot use `.*` to match files like `.file`, because `.*` or `.*?` will also match `..` or `.`. `.[^.]*` matches files like `.file`, while `..?*` matches files like `..foo` (`*` matches zero or more characters while `?` matches exactly one).

Comment: You also need something like `..?*` to catch entries that start with “..” (e.g `..foo`).

Comment: @Chris: OK, I started this picky madness, you are right ;)

Comment: it's not only to use the "right" glob patterns, it's also about the amount of matched items. in directories with a huge amount of files the shell is most likely not able to give 50k files in one turn to `rm`. so, deleting the content of a directory with * is not the wisest way, imho.

Comment: I think explaining `xargs` is a little beyond the scope of this question. One could e.g. start thinking about that when the shell complains argument list lenghts.

Comment: i think it's not out of scope because i think OP is not sure how to achieve his ultimate problem / solution: remove all the content of the directory. OP is just doing the general "wrong" thing by having already a solution (a bad one) in mind and asking why this solution causes problems. better approach would be: "how to delete all files in a directory without deleting the directory itself?" OP's solution will cause problems due the very nature of how globbing works.

Comment: @akira to avoid that issue, one can [simply delete and recreate the directory itself](http://superuser.com/a/379788/35237)

Comment: @TobiasKienzler: you are addressing the wrong person.

Comment: I am pretty sure this it not what the question was asking about.

Answer (score 14):

If you want to remove a directory and all its contents, you can `chdir` into the parent directory and them `rm -rf` that directory by name, bypassing the entire globbing question.  If you want to remove the contents but keep the directory, it's easiest to remove all and then recreate the directory.

It is complex to come up with a glob that will match all possible directory entries save . and ..; it's easy to come up with a simple answer (e.g., `* .??*`) that will work almost always in practice.  This is OK for interactive use, since it's easy to remember and the times it doesn't work can be caught with a post-rm `ls -a`.  For a script, it's easier to do the remove all and recreate the empty directory.

Comment: That is what i would suggest as well: throw away the directory and done

Comment: Even thou it's not the answer it is a good idea.

Answer (score 10):

Since I think this question is more about what * does (and not rm), let's try another approach.

---

If you are unsure what the * does, you can "test" first using a harmless command like echo.
Before you run this, try to guess what they will show if you run them in your home dir.

```
echo *
echo .*
```

But first let's create a playground so we can play with the stars and see what we end up with.

```
mkdir ~/star_test/
cd ~/star_test/
>.file1
>file2
```

Now in this dir we have this:

```
cj@zap:~/star_test$ ls -1a
.
..
.file1
file2
```

Now notice what the * expands into using the echo command:

```
cj@zap:~/star_test$ echo *
file2
cj@zap:~/star_test$ echo .*
. .. .file1
```

So let's see what happens with the rm command

```
cj@zap:~/star_test$ rm -rf *
cj@zap:~/star_test$ ls -1a
.
..
.file1
```

As you see he did only remove the file2, since * only expanded to file2.
If you would type rm -rf .* that would be the same as writing

```
rm -rf . .. .file1
```

And to be honest, that do not look fun ;)

Hope this clarifies the * part of your question.

---

**Update:** 
However as Ankur Goel points out there is some kind of protection built into rm (kind of unusual for shell commands :)

Let's create a new playground:

```
cd ~/star_test/
mkdir -p test1/test2/test3
sudo chown root.root test1
cd test1/test2/test3/
>.file1
>file2
```

So now we have this again, but with test1 owned by root as protection if 
rm start to go berserk.

```
cj@zap:~/star_test/test1/test2/test3$ ls -a
.  ..  file2  .file1
cj@zap:~/star_test/test1/test2/test3$ echo .*
. .. .file1
```

So let's remove everything:

```
cj@zap:~/star_test/test1/test2/test3$ rm -rf .*
rm: cannot remove directory `.'
rm: cannot remove directory `..'
cj@zap:~/star_test/test1/test2/test3$ ls -a
.  ..  file2
```

And it looks like rm did not remove . and .. even if we told him to!!!

So after this long answer it turns out to be safe to remove everything in a dir with this:

```
rm -rf * .*
```

But I would use this with care, since I'm not sure all implementations of rm behaves like this!

Answer (score 8):

Yes.  rm -rf will only delete files and folders in the current directory, and will not ascend up the file tree.  rm will also not follow symlinks and delete the files they point to, so you don't accidentally prune other parts of your filesystem.

Comment: As given it will not necessarily delete _all_ files and directories in the current directory.

Answer (score 1):

A much easier way to empty an entire folder, also avoiding the "too many arguments" issues discussed in [this answer](https://superuser.com/a/126647/35237), is to simply delete and recreate the directory itself. To make sure this works correctly when you are in a symlinked directory, use the following lines:

```
cd ..
rm -rf $(readlink -f yourdir) #remove the directory, treat the case of a symlink
                        # by using readlink, to recreate the linked-to directory
mkdir $(readlink -f yourdir) # recreate the directory to have it empty
cd yourdir
```

(If you uses `yourdir` instead of `$(readlink -f yourdir)` you'd only replace the link while the original location remains full)

Comment: This can break things relying on the folder's inode, and throw away permissions, atime/mtime/ctime/btime, extended attributes, and access control lists.

Comment: @DanielBeck thanks, good points. Although I wonder, what would validly rely on the inode apart from hardlinks (on directories, which are strongly discouraged anyway)? But permissions etc is important. So in the most general case one _should_ probably use `xargs`...

Comment: OS X contains a mechanism that can handle files and folders being moved around and still retain the association. Most visibly in the *Open Recent Documents* menu. AFAICT, it uses inodes to accomplish that internally. [More info](http://superuser.com/questions/368288/how-did-xcode-osx-do-that-moved-an-xcode-project-to-another-location-xcode-aut/368297#368297). I wouldn't be surprised if other systems implemented something similar e.g. in APIs for GUI programs.

Answer (score 0):

If you don't want to move one level up like mpez0 said and `rm -rf` this specific folder, there is a way to work on *all* directories/files except `.` and `..` in the current folder by doing:

```
rm -rf $(ls -A)
```

Of course, if any of the directories/files contains one of the characters in the shell `IFS` special variable (e.g. space, tab, newline), you might want to change the IFS first, run the command, then restore IFS.

Answer (score 0):

There is a hidden problem when using `*` in Unix shell:

When you have file names start with a dash (`-`), these file names could be mistakenly interpreted as options by the programs, such as **rm(1)**.

In this case, for example, if you have a file named `-f` in working directory, this file won't be removed by `rm -rf *`, as it will be treated as another `-f` option by **rm(1)**; or having a file named `-i` would negating the effect of your early specified `-f`.

GNU operating systems are more likely to be affected by this issue, because its **getopt(3)** functions won't stop at first non-option argument, when looking for options; as a result, even you put `*` after some non-options, on a GNU system (or using GNU **rm** since it has their own **getopt(3)** implementation that behaves very similar to the one in **GLIBC**), strangely-named files may still be interpreted as options.

Based on Benjamin Bannier's answer, to really remove all files in working directory, put a `--` before file names, like

```sh
rm -rf -- .[^.]* ..?* *
```

Further reading:

*UNIX-HATERS Handbook*, section *2, Welcome, User!*, *Consistently Inconsistent*.